# Efficient way to make read and write operation in the same table simuntaneously..?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a production issue for the below condition.

I have a table with 62 million rows and an user has attempted to insert 50000 rows into the table using upload functionality. Meanwhile, another 100 user has attempted to read the table. Because, of this simultaneous read and write operation, the database got hung up and as a result the page is not loaded.

We have already a sufficient index keys for the column that we are doing the read operation.

I have an idea about using views, but my doubt is, if we are using views for read operation, then whether the concurrent write operation values will get reflected into the views?

Kindly let me know any other possible ways.

Comment: no idea what you mean by 'upload functionality'...is that a simple insert, or is that some sort of..well..functionality?...the user is using to get the rows into the table?  Microsoft supports with (nolock) as a method of avoiding locking...not really sure how a view could help

Comment: Which RDBMS?  MySQL or SQL Server?  The answer will be different depending on that.

Answer (score 1):

This answer applies to Microsoft SQL Server only (not MySQL), which I'm assuming is your RDBMS based on the additional tags (sql-server-2008/-r2).

If you do not care about "dirty reads" -- you have two options to basically ignore the locks imposed by the insert operations.

At the top of your script add `set transaction isolation level read uncommitted` or after each table add `with(nolock)` -- they are effectively the same thing, but the former applies to all tables in your query, and the latter only applies to the tables you append it to.

ex:

```
set transaction isolation level read uncommited
select *
from mytable
where id between 1 and 100
```

ex2:

```
select *
from mytable with(nolock)
where id between 1 and 100
```

NB: this ONLY helps with select statements.

If you are unsure what a dirty read is, you should read up on them before allowing them into your application.

If this is not an option, then you would likely need to look at creating a snapshot or replicated copy of your database (I prefer replication), and point ALL read operations to that copy of the data.